# multiple-cucumber-html-reporter with webdriverio

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

Cucumber Feature is being marked as failed even if any all scenario are passed with rerun in multiple-cucumber-html-reporter with webdriverio. I'm running tests on Jenkins which is generating html report

These are the config i have setup in wdio config file

```
    [ 'cucumberjs-json', {
    
                jsonFolder: reportsFolder + '/json/',
    
                language: 'en',
             
                reportFilePerRetry: true,
    
            },
    
        ]
```

```
 cucumberOpts: {
        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
        require: ['./features/step-definitions/*/*.ts', './features/step-definitions/*.ts'],
        // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
        backtrace: false,
        retry: 3,
        ignoreBadJsonFile: true,
        // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
        requireModule: [],
        // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
        dryRun: false,
        // format: [

        //     'json:reports/json/*.json',
      
        //     'progress'
      
        //   ],
        //   plugin: ('json:reports/json/*.json'),
        // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
        failFast: false,
        // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
        snippets: true,
        // <boolean> hide source uris
        source: true,
        // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
        strict: false,
        // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
        tagExpression: '',

        // <number> timeout for step definitions
        timeout: 30000000,
        // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
        ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false
    },
```

I need to mark Cucumber Feature as passed when all scenarios are passed in a feature file with reruns
Please help here Thanks